# Deleting images by tags and created date

Tags: java, cloudinary

I use client-side picture upload of cloudinary and my use case is the following:

- user uploads image using javascript -> image is automatically tagged with tmp tag (already supported)
- when a user submits the form, the server processes all the images and through the admin_api it removes tmp tag from them (already supported)
- cron job contacts cloudinary to remove all images tagged with tmp that are older than 1 day (i can't find how to do it)

I wonder how can I delete all images by tags and older than 1 day using cloudinary admin API?

Comment: What do you mean by "tag"? Add a tag keyword in a database? In HTML output? In localStorage?

Comment: a tag is a keyword ,used by cloudinary, assigned to uploaded pictures for later group reference

Comment: Yes, but where is it saved?

Comment: @BramVanroy tags are used and saved into remote cloudinary services, it is neither in my localStorage nor my app database.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary currently does not support automatic deletions. You can use the Admin API once in a while (e.g., once a day) to list all resources by their upload time, and delete them.

Comment: thanks , my workaround was to start a cron job every X hours that make a call to cloudinary admin api, find pictures by tags "temporary" then, in my backend server, filter by created_at older than 1h, finally delete all filtered picture by another call to cloudinary delete admin api by picture_ids. 
it is true that this is not the best solution but i use it until cloudinary make the requested api.

Comment: what i was looking for is a cloudinary api that delete by tags and start_at parameters and not a support for automatic deleting, this would make my life easier if exists.